# problems with insert datetime from calender in asp.net to microsoft sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to insert selected date from calender in asp.net to Microsoft SQL database.

When I select time like `01/04/2012` its work, but when trying to insert `30/01/2012` I'm getting the message:

> The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in
>   an out-of-range datetime value.

When I create the `datetime` object by using `closeDateCalender.SelectedDate`,
the  code in c# is :

```
sb.AppendFormat("Values('{0}', '{1}' ,'{2}', '{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}')",
    opportunity.UserId, 
    opportunity.AccountId, 
    opportunity.OpportunityName, 
    opportunity.CloseDate, 
    opportunity.Stage, 
    opportunity.Probability, 
    opportunity.Amount, 
    opportunity.Description);
String prefix = "INSERT INTO Opportunities " + "([User_Id],Account_Id,Opportunity_Name,Close_Date,Stage,Probabilty,Amount,[Description])";
        command = prefix + sb.ToString();
```

any idea how to solve it???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server is set to accept dates in American format rather than European. If you reformat the date so that it's in the format `yyyy-MM-dd` it will work.

Try this:

```
sb.AppendFormat("Values('{0}', '{1}' ,'{2}', '{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}')",
  opportunity.UserId, 
  opportunity.AccountId, 
  opportunity.OpportunityName, 
  opportunity.CloseDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), 
  opportunity.Stage, 
  opportunity.Probability, 
  opportunity.Amount, 
  opportunity.Description);
```

Answer (score 1):

To get rid off all this pain of formatting and other things, use prepared statemnts or parameterized queries instead, and it will take care of all this formatting stuff. Something like:

```
string YourSQL = "INSERT INTO Tablename(columns list) Values(?, ?, ?, ..) ";

command.Parameters.Add("CloseDate", 
                       DbType.DateTime).Value = opportunity.CloseDate;
...
...// do the same for the rest of the fields.
```

This way the `opportunity.CloseDate` should be of data type `DateTime`.